# Handle Azure CLI output on bash for az sql db list

Tags: bash, azure

This instruction returns 1 if a database exists and 0 otherwise.

```
az sql db list --resource-group demo-group --server demo-server --query "[?name == 'debo-database'] | length(@)"
```

The problem is how to use this in if conditions like

```
[ $(az sql db list --resource-group demo-group --server demo-server --query "[?name == 'debo-database'] | length(@)") -eq 1 ] && echo "exists"
```

The above-mentioned condition doesn't work as planned...

Answer (score 1):

You're mistakenly checking the stdout **output** of the command to be the value "1" instead of its **return code**. Use `&&` conditional chaining for a non-zero return code (by inverting the sense of the original `az` return code with `!`):

```
! az sql db list --resource-group demo-group --server demo-server --query "[?name == 'debo-database'] | length(@)" && echo "exists"
```

... or the same thing but more verbosely with an `if` statement:

```
if ! az sql db list --resource-group demo-group --server demo-server --query "[?name == 'debo-database'] | length(@)"; then echo "exists"; fi
```

The above check for any non-zero return code from `az`. To check the return code more explicitly for being 1:

```
az sql db list --resource-group demo-group --server demo-server --query "[?name == 'debo-database'] | length(@)"
case $? in
  (1) echo "exists";;
esac
```

Comment: This example returns 1 instead of "exists"

Comment: Sorry, which example of the 3? All of them echo "exists", just like the Q does.

Comment: Sorry, but of all of them. I've tried and had no success. Also, I have to add that examples return 0 in case of DB doesn't exist.